# Otrs (3.2.10) )installation on Centos

Tags: otrs

I'm trying to install otrs-3.2.10-02 on centos 6 using rpm package. But it shows following error.

error: failed dependencies :
       perl-core module is required by otrs-3.2.10-02.noarch
       cronie module is required by otrs-3.2.10-02.noarch

I tried to get these missing modules but couldn't get them installed.

Can anybody help me to get this working ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What command did you use to install OTRS? If you use `yum` the dependencies should be taken care of automatically.

Please check
[the chapter about installing on CentOS in the OTRS manual](http://doc.otrs.org/3.2/en/html/installation.html#installation-on-centos)

Comment: Thanks you for quick revert. Yes, I have used yum install command but it shows the error described above. Is there anything else I need to check ?

Comment: please do `yum upgrade` first, then install as per the manual. If you still have a problem, please paste the output of the error message here.

Comment: Hi Michiel. Have run that command "yum upgrade" and my packages seem to be updated but still error persists.                                 Error : Missing dependency : cronie is needed by package otrs-3.2.10-02.noarch
Error : Missing dependency : perl-core is needed by package otrs-3.2.10-02.noarch